# get relationships from an NSDictionaryResultType

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a results array containing the fetch results from core data. It is an array of Dictionaries (according to NSDictionaryResultType).

The object I fetch is a car, car has name,make,model,color (which I can see all in the array). However car also has a toCarParts relationship. This NSSet contains carPart objects (wheel, tire, etc...)

How do I access this (is it faulted in the dictionary?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [- (void)setPropertiesToFetch:(NSArray *)values](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-SW25) states:

> The property descriptions may represent attributes, to-one
>   relationships, or expressions.

It is therefore not possible to get the `NSSet` of a to-many relationship with `NSDictionaryResultType`.

Comment: so how would you suggest I structure the request to get the managed object with all relationships? but obtain unique objects (no duplicates)

Comment: @Will: If you have 4 Car objects with identical attributes, which one should the request return?

Comment: any (just need one), its the same car

Comment: @Will: I can't think of a fetch request which does what you want. It would probably be better to avoid this situation by testing for duplicates before a new Car object is added to the database.

Comment: ok, I thought there weren't duplicates in my parsing but I will check